# Does 32-bit builds of CentOS 7 exist?

Tags: centos, system-installation, 32bit

I have a project which must use 32 bit Linux system. I want to use CentOS 7. However there are no 32 bit builds of CentOS 7 in default CentOS repositories. I have found some builds here

http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7.3.1611/isos/i386/

Are these - official builds? Can I use them without problems? Does any other official builds of CentOS 7 32 bit exist?

Answer (score 3):

Below is the official url for Alternative Architectures. Here we can download i386 image.

https://wiki.centos.org/Download

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that seems to be official:

https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2015-October/021430.html

Comment: [AltArch SIG stuff](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/AltArch) seems to be community-maintained builds based of the x86-64 ones from the Core SIG. Dunno how official that makes it.

Comment: @muru Official enough that official CentOS staff announces it and hosts it on their servers.

Comment: Ah, but: "We will retain the requirement that all 'CentOS' branded content must be hosted, built and delivered from infra operated by the CentOS Infra team, signed with a CentOS key (run by the Core SIG), must be freely redistributeable." Given those requirements, that can't be helped if the AltArch SIG want to call it CentOS.

Comment: (What I want to say is that while the Core SIG would try not to break the AltArch-supported builds, they probably won't exercise the same level of caution extended to x86-64 builds.)

Comment: @muru Well, the OP won't find anything "more official" than this in any case. I'd advise him to "suck it and see".

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, they are the official builds, and you can use any of the [CentOS](http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7.3.1611/isos/i386/) without fear of a problem as I have checked [CentOS Mirror](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708.iso) and it works fine.

Comment: The file you link to seems to be a 64-bit CentOS distribution (judging from the filename).